# Material Design - Green Floating Acción Button with a tick?

Tags: color, google-material-design

I have an image processing app. The user first selects the photos he wants to process, and then selects the FAB (which has a green background and a white tick as icon). When the user selects the FAB, a speed dial opens, and the FAB's icon changes from the tick to a cross to close the speed dial.

I know that in some countries the tick means what in english the cross means.

So, should I change my FAB Design for those countries?
If so, what do you suggest me?

Thank you

Comment: In some countries/cultures the symbol “✔︎” means “no/close/stop”, the way that “✖︎” does in ‘normal’ countries/cultures? That’s a first for me. Where is this the case?

Comment: I think it's in Finland and other countries

Comment: So, the question is: for this countries should I use the cross where the tick is used, and viceversa? Or should I use a generic icon?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. The _Check mark_ page on Wikipedia mentions Sweden and Finland as countries where ✔︎ means ‘incorrect answer’. I don’t think you need to design any different icons for those two countries, especially since people there are perfectly used to these two icons being used the ‘English’ way as well, and green and red both have the same connotations, too. It’s only really when marking answers as correct/incorrect that ✔︎ is used (sometimes) to mean ‘incorrect’—your case is different, because it means ‘select by clicking here’, which I’d say works the same there too.

Comment: Have a look at [these comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24222829#24222829) by joojaa, a resident Finnish user. Perhaps it’s not quite as clear-cut as I thought it would be. Perhaps it would be safer to go with **+** (plus) and **÷** (minus) instead—stylised for maximum clarity and disambiguity, of course. Unless there’s some place where they’ve reversed the mathematical symbols as well, I’d say that ought to be fairly safe.